# How to split an integer?

Tags: python, integer, decimal

I'm not really sure how to go about this but I'm trying to make a guessing game and give feedback on the user's input. For example if the number to be guessed is 6709 and the user inputs 6908 the input would be wrong but still partially correct. If one portion of the integer is correct the program will tell the user it's correct and do the same if its wrong.

Lets says the number to be guessed is 6709

And the user inputs 6908

The program would produce a output like this (Yes No Yes No)

What would be the method to split an integer into portions so that I could give feedback? Or is there a decimal place technique for this?

Comment: The user is really just guessing characters in a string. If you treat the integer as a string, you can examine its component characters using indexing.

Comment: put the INT into and array where each digit is one occurrence and compare each element

Comment: or as @NicholasFlees says, that's probably even easier

Comment: `print(['Yes' if c == guess[i] else 'No' for i,c in enumerate(key)])` if key is 6709 and guess is 6908

Comment: `[['No','Yes'][i1 == i2] for i1,i2 in  zip(input('Type a number'),'6709')]` (`raw_input` if Python 2)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's an even simpler solution than any of these:
convert number to list

```
import numpy as np

num1 = 1234
num2 = 1245
a = list(str(num1))
b = list(str(num2))    
// a = [1,2,3,4]
// b = [1,2,4,5]

c = np.in1d(a,b)
```

The resulting c is then:

```
array([ True, True, False,  False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: how does the user go from an int to a list? int->string->cast char to int in list?

Comment: nt->string->list(str) or   [int(x) for x in str(num)]

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre, you should probably include that in your answer because that's what OP is asking about.

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre `a = [num1]` isn't splitting `num1` into its component digits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be best off converting the numbers to strings and then comparing each character:

```
userInput = 6908
answer = 6709

userInputStr = str(userInput)
answerStr = str(answer)
outputStr = " "
print(outputStr.join(["Y" if i == j else "N" for i, j in zip(userInputStr, answerStr)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been documented here that an easy way to approach this is to treat the integers like strings, but I thought it might be fun to show an approach that refrained from converting the integers to strings.

You could write a method that takes an integer argument and returns a list of the digits. It might look something like this:

```
def get_digits(num):
    digits = []
    while num > 0:
        digits.insert(0, num % 10)
        num /= 10
    return digits
```

**Note that you'll need to use the `//=` operator for integer division if you're using Python 3.**

So in order to get the list of `yes` and `no` values for two integers, you could do this:

```
def get_element_wise_equality(a, b):
    # a and b are integers
    digits_a = get_digits(a)
    digits_b = get_digits(b)
    if len(digits_a) != len(digits_b):
        return None
    result = []
    for i in range(len(digits_a)):
        if digits_a[i] == digits_b[i]:
            result.append('yes')
        else
            result.append('no')
    return result
```